# C - execl(): can't execute file located in another directory

Tags: c, linux, unix, exec, file-permissions

I'm trying to execute a binary file named "helloworld" (compiled from a source.c) located in another directory with my program notify.c. Here's where my files are located:

/home/morts/Desktop/helloworld

/home/morts/Desktop/Homeworks/notify

I tried with:

```
const char *cmd = "/home/morts/Desktop/helloworld";
execl(cmd, "LOL", NULL);
perror("execl()");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

but I get:

```
execl(): Permission denied
```

If helloworld would be located in the same directory of notify, I'd simply put "./helloworld", but since they are in different directories, how can I fix this?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Has the user running `notify` the rights to execute `helloworld`?

Comment: I suppose so: if I type "stat notify" I get:

Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/morts )   Gid: ( 1000/morts)

and "stat helloworld":

Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/morts)   Gid: ( 1000/morts)

Comment: Have you tried `execl(cmd, "helloworld", "LOL", NULL);`?

Comment: Yes @AnishRam, and I always get "permission denied"

Comment: I doubt that's the problem, but the `NULL` must be cast, `(char*)NULL`, according to the specs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but still nothing :-(
I also tried to change the working directory with chdir(), but I don't get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to execute an file hello under path /bin/test by execl without any parameters
try following:

> execl("/bin/test/hello", "hello", (char*)NULL);

Check following otherwise you may get a permission denial error:

1. The first argument must be an `/path/your_file` without any **space**
2. The second argument must be "**your_file**" the same as in first argument
3. the last argument must be (char*)NULL

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the path is correct and you have the right permissions to execute this file by trying to run the command directly in the terminal :

```
/home/morts/Desktop/helloworld
```

If it works then you have to check that the user running your program also have the permission to execute that file.

Comment: /home/morts/Desktop/helloworld works and gives me Hello, world!